# How to find the document in mongodb where array size is greater than 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, express

I want to find all the documents which are present and have array size greater than 1

My MongoDB collection looks like

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5eaaeedd00101108e1123452"),
  "type" : ["admin","teacher","student"]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5eaaeedd00101108e1123453"),
  "type" : ["student"], 
}
```

How I find the document which has more than 1 type

Comment: Starting in MongoDB 4.4, $where no longer supports the deprecated BSON type JavaScript with scope (i.e. BSON type 15). The use of JavaScript with scope for the $where function has been deprecated since version 4.2.1. Ref https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/ 
So when you upgrade your version,it wont work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You can use [$gt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt)

db.collectionName.find({"type": {$gt: 1} });

2. You can use [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where)

db.collectionName.find( { $where: "type > 1" } );

Comment: `$gt` to directly compare arrays to integers doesn't do what you may think it does. See "Type Bracketing" in the MongoDB manual. Generally - this kind of comparison will always return "false".

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this. This is working version > 4.2

```
db.collection.find({
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $size: "$type"
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    })
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CxYa4DYad4m)

If you use less, you can do something like follwoing

```
db.collection.find({
  type: {
    $gt: {
      $size: 1
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: The query `{type:{$gt:{$size:1}}}` doesn't work: https://mongoplayground.net/p/HSuYFa848fX - it always returns 0 elements

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.find({type: {$gt: 1}})
```

just change the name of the colletion

---

`gt` means greatter, you can see more about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/)

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution for this problem is as follows:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      {
        $size: "$arrayfield"
      },
      1
    ]
  }
})
```

All other solutions do not work. Tried it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to tackle the problem is to ask:

> how can I find the document in MongoDB that has an element in the
> (n)-th position in the array field?

To achieve this, you can use the following query

```
{ "type.1": { $exists: true } }
```

this solution is cleaner and it does not require the use of aggregate pipelines